# How to match alphanumerical order in both Google Drive and Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula, google-drive-api, alphanumeric

On my Google Drive I have a folder containing 2006 files.
These files are sorted by names. (from A -> Z)
Here's the exact order of the files inside my folder: https://gist.github.com/cuzureau/a36deb8e02ab0f2e0523cd58f2cf0950

Now, I also have a Google Sheet with the same file names written in a column. One file name per cell. They are order alphabetically (from A -> Z)
Here's the exact order of the files inside the column: https://gist.github.com/cuzureau/6fe722b821ce3aa60b697819b64d6b05

The files names are not sorted in the same order.
How can I do that ?

Maybe I should use a formula in Google Sheets to reorder the files names in the column ?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do? Why not copy/paste the file list into Sheets, and sort both there? which sort order are you using in Drive? (see [this](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2375177)) (also this might be better suited to [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/)?)

Comment: I'm trying to get the same order in both system but they sort names differently. I cannot copy paste names in the first column because they are other columns with information related to this one.

Comment: Can you share a sanitized copy of the sheets?

Comment: What do you mean by sanitized in this case ?

Comment: That no contains sensible information

Comment: I edited my question. There is no sensible information.

Answer (score 1):

These are two possible solutions using Google Apps Script (both tested with the first 100 files):

##### Grab the names directly using DriveApp

1. Enter in your sheet and click on `Extensions > Apps Script`
   [image]
2. Copy the folder id where the files lives
3. Copy this script.

```js
const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
function myFunction() {
  const folderId = "<FOLDER_ID>"
  // Get all files in the folder
  const files = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).getFiles()
  const toShortFiles = []
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    // save all the names
    const file = files.next()
    toShortFiles.push(file.getName())
  }
  // short A-Z
  const shorted = toShortFiles.sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b)).map(n => [n])
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, shorted.length, 1).setValues(shorted)
}
```

#### Short directly creating a new sheet

This is an alternative if you have more data in the same row

```js
function shortRows() {
  /* Create a new sheet */
  const shortedSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().insertSheet('shortedSheet')
  const range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn())
  const values = range.getValues()
  /* Short by name */
  const result = values.sort((a, b) => {
    return a[0].toString().localeCompare(b[0].toString())
  })
  /* Paste the data in the new sheet */
  shortedSheet.getRange(1, 1, result.length, result[0].length).setValues(result)
}
```

If you don't want to create a new sheet, you have available the methods `moveTo` and `moveRows` I invite you to test them.

###### Documentation:

- [String.prototype.localeCompare()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)
- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)
- [Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet)

Comment: Seems promising ! But I cannot find `Extensions > Apps Script` when in my sheet.

Comment: I edit my question to add an image

Comment: Ok thanks I had to convert the sheet from .xlsx to Google spreadsheet format to get that button to appear !

Comment: I took your second script because I have more data in the same row. Execution succeeded. But nothing changed. Still got the same order. The file names list in the original spreadsheet are in between A6 and A2006

Comment: I'm gonna try it with the full list, that's odd

Comment: Seems that Google Drive is using a different kind of algorithm to sort the files. Trying to reproduce it.

Comment: do you have any news on this ?

Comment: I suggest opening a new issue in Google Issue tracker https://issuetracker.google.com and ask for this topic. no luck from my side